# A blank document is uploaded for the sender view

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am trying to upload pdf files to DocuSign to generate `sender view`. There are two files, one is 13KB and another is 300KB.

Following is a function that accepts the document in `7-Bit` encoding and converts to `base64` before sending to DocuSign.

The problem is, the documents are reflected in the sender view generated but I can only see the one which is 13KB. Another document is blank. What could be the reason for this?

```
 createEnvelopeWithEmbeddedLink({ subject, documentList, email, name, userId, status }) {

        let _this = this;
        return Promise.coroutine(function* () {
            let baseURL = yield _this.baseUrl();
            // Step-1: Create an envelope with embedded document
            let apiURLCE = `${baseURL}/envelopes`;
            let requestPayloadCE = {
                status: status, 
                /**
                 * @see ENVELOPE_STATUS
                 */
                emailSubject: subject,
                recipients: {}
            };

            // Create a document object list
            for (let i = 0; i < documentList.length; i++) {
                let dobj = {
                    documentId: i + 1,
                    name: documentList[i].filename,
                    documentBase64: Buffer.from(documentList[i].content).toString('base64')
                };

                if (requestPayloadCE.documents)
                    requestPayloadCE.documents.push(dobj);
                else
                    requestPayloadCE.documents = [dobj];
            }

            // Create the recipient/signer list
            requestPayloadCE.recipients.signers = [
                {
                    email: email,
                    name: name,
                    recipientId: 1,
                    clientUserId: userId
                }
            ];

            requestPayloadCE = JSON.stringify(requestPayloadCE);
            let requestOptionsCE = _initRequest(apiURLCE, 'POST', requestPayloadCE, _accountDetails(pvtProps.get(_this)));
            let responseCE = yield _request(requestOptionsCE);
            return responseCE;
        })();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your json Payload?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample request to [create an envelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) with multiple documents.

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes
```

Request Payload

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Please sign the agreement",
  "status": "sent",
  "recipients": {
      "signers": [
          {
              "email": "janedoe@acme.com",
              "name": "jane doe",
              "recipientId": 1,
              "routingOrder": 1
          }
      ]
  },
  "documents": [
      {
          "documentId": "1",
          "name": "Doc1",
          "fileExtension": "txt",
          "documentBase64": "VGVzdCBEb2N1bWVudA=="
      },
      {
          "documentId": "2",
          "name": "Doc2",
          "fileExtension": "txt",
          "documentBase64": "VGVzdCBEb2N1bWVudA=="
      }     
  ]
}
```